# Looking for a way to turn a rails controller into a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a rails controller, which, along with it's helper and views, is pretty much stand-alone and useful.  I would like to turn it into a gem.  I have not built any gems, and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/) and prosper.